# Kendo button calling a javascript function on click

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a HTML input like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="saveForm" value="Save" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
```

here's the `validateForm` function called when the button is clicked:

```
function validateForm() {
    if (someErrorCondition) {
        alert("error");
        return false;
    }
    reallySubmitForm();
}
```

I want to replace this button with a Kendo Button, and I'm doing like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("save")
    .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "submit"})
    .ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Images/save.png"))
    .Events(e => e.Click("return validateForm"))    <---------  here's the problem
    .Content("Save")
)
```

The problem is that, if I have

```
.Events(e => e.Click("return validateForm"))
```

the button isn't rendered correctly: the "return" word is messing it up. If I have this

```
.Events(e => e.Click("validateForm"))
```

it's rendered correctly and the function is called. However, when clicked, the button submits the form anyway, without caring with validation.

How can I achieve the former behaviour with this Kendo Button?

Comment: What is `someErrorCondition` in the function from? Instead of adding the click function that way through the extension method try doing it the classic way with JQuery. `$("#save").click(function(){...});` It's possible that `if (someErrorCondition)` is returning false

Comment: No, the `someErrorCondition` works fine. As I said, the `validateForm` function works perfectly with a regular HTML submit input. As for the JQuery, you are right, the `$("#save").click(function(){...});` works, that's how I worked around it. I was asking if there was a way of recreating the `return validateForm` I had previously in a Kendo Button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [e.preventDefault()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/click#preventing-the-default-action-of-the-dom-event) instead of returning false in order to stop the submit event. That's the recommended way anyway. :)

Comment: How can I put that in my code? Where? I tried adding `e.preventDefault();` where `return false;` was but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try Following code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
.Name("save")
.HtmlAttributes( new {type = "submit"})
.ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Images/save.png"))
.Events(e => e.Click("validateForm"))
.Content("Save"))

function validateForm(e) {
  if (someErrorCondition) {
    alert("error");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
 else {
      reallySubmitForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work, as I stated in the comment to @dooart's answer

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with only "**return**" and it works. But using  e.preventDefault() does not do the trick for me.

Comment: Satya, it doesn't work: only `return` breaks the function and the code that comes after isn't run. However, since it's a button of type `submit`, the submit is always done. With the code I had initially, `return false` would break the function and the action too.

Comment: Oh.My bad then. You are checking for some error condition there. Why don't you put that "reallySubmitForm();" in else block. May it work.

Comment: No Satya, it won't work. You can have a function with nothing in it: the submit action is always called when pressing a submit type button - unless you prevent it, that's what I want